# How to display images from a nested json array in each div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I'm having trouble in displaying images from a nested JSON array because its displaying all images in one div container instead of one image per div container I don't know now what should I do? Im sorry for my bad English anyway here is my codes

**HTML**

```
<div class='e-mapMarker'></div>
<div id='search-result'></div>
```

**JSON**

```
var places = [{
  "country_name": "Denmark",
  "latitude": 56,
  "longitude": 10,
  "status": "OK",
  "site_name": "Denmark",
  "company_logo": "nothinglogo.png",
  "serial_number": "12345",
  "products": [{
    "image": "someimage.png"
  }]
},
{
  "country_name": "Zaire",
  "latitude": -20,
  "longitude": 30,
  "status": "OK",
  "site_name": "Zaire",
  "company_logo": "nothinglogo.png",
  "serial_number": "67890",
  "products": [{
    "image": "someimage.png"
  }]
},
{
  "country_name": "Vietnam",
  "latitude": 16,
  "longitude": 106,
  "status": "NO",
  "site_name": "Vietnam",
  "company_logo": "nothinglogo.png",
  "serial_number": "1111",
  "products": [{
    "image": "someimage.png"
  }]
},
{
  "country_name": "Taiwan",
  "latitude": 23.5,
  "longitude": 121,
  "status": "OK",
  "site_name": "Taiwan",
  "company_logo": "nothinglogo.png",
  "serial_number": "22222",
  "products": [{
    "image": "someimage.png"
  }]
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function displayData(e) {
  var html = '';
  var html2 = '';
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapContainer'), i = 0,
      dataIndex, tooltipDiv, key, item,
      mapMarkers = $(mapDiv).find('.e-mapMarker'), index = 0;
  var collection = [];
  collection = collection.concat(flsSites, flsInstallation, flsProduct);

  var sites = $('#fls_site').attr('data-flag');
  var installation = $('#fls_installation').attr('data-flag');
  var product = $('#fls_products').attr('data-flag');

  for (i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode == mapMarkers[i]) {
      index = i;
    }
  }

  html += '<div id="infocontainer" class="map_element">';
  html += "<div class='p-image'><img src='src/images/" + 
  collection[index].company_logo + "' /></div>";
  html += '<div class="popupdetail">';
  html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Name: ' + collection[index].site_name + '</div>'; 
  html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Status: ' + collection[index].status + '</div>';
  html += '<div class="p-name"> Country: ' + collection[index].country_name + '</div>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';

  html2 += '<div class="rightcontainer">';
  html2 += collection[index].products.map(product => "<div class='p-name'><img src='src/images/" + product.image + "' /><br></div>");
  html2 += '<div id="imagedetail">';
  html2 += '<span class="details">' + collection[index].products[0].pump + '</span>';
  html2 += '</div>';
  html2 += '</div>';
  if (!document.getElementById('map_tooltip')) {
    tooltipdiv = $("<div></div>").attr('id', "map_tooltip");
    $(document.body).append(tooltipdiv);
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
      "display": "none", "padding": "5px",
      "position": "absolute",
      "z-index": "13000",
      "cursor": "default",
      "font-family": "Segoe UI",
      "color": "#707070",
      "font-size": "12px", "pointer-events": "none",
      "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
      "border": "1px solid #707070"
    });
  } else {
    tooltipdiv = $("#map_tooltip");
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
      "left": (e.pageX + 5),
      "top": (e.pageY + 5)
    });
    $(tooltipdiv).html(html).show("slow");
    $('#search-result').append(html2);
  }
}
```

With this code my result is it generates the divs but it contains two images(1 and 2) instead of div 1 contains image 1 then div 2 contains image 2

Comment: Please share your JSON.

Comment: @Shiladitya I updated my post and included my JSON

Comment: @Kyle Can you update your question with the HTML markup?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez all I can share is the marker of the map in which var html will be triggered and then the div that is result container in which the var html2 will be render

Comment: @Kyle Are you using a map library? So I'll can reproduce your issue to find a solution.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez yes I am, I am using syncfusion javascript and it was required to me by my boss to be used in his project

Comment: @Kyle Sorry for replying late, which image you are talking about (`company-logo` or `product.image`)???

Comment: @Kyle Can you reproduce this code through https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Shiladitya i am using product.image

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I loved too but I have a hard time using jsfiddle